# Run a URL in background without opening in browser vb.net on clicking a button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008, httprequest

I am using aspx with vb.I have a textbox and a login button.

On clicking this button,if username is correct, I need to run a URL in background without showing in browser.

```
http://example.com/sms.php?email=username
```

Username is get from the textbox

```
Dim url As String
url = "example.com/sms.php?email=" & txtUser.Text
CreateObject("wscript.shell").run(url)
```

Comment: show your button click code?

Comment: Dim url As String

            url = "http://example.com/sms.php?email=" + txtUser.Text
            CreateObject("wscript.shell").run(url)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an async request to the server. You can use [jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or native [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to perform it on a client-side. If you want to perform request on a server-side you can use [WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f(v=vs.110).aspx) or [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx). Give me to know if you need a detailed example with on of this features.

Comment: Every link contains some examples. You should specify what exactly you want to use

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebRequest Class or you can use HTTPClient class and Get the response stream from the URL, Then you can parse the response in memmory from the data for example if your data is HTML you can Load it in an XDocument and extract whatever information is required from the response , and it is better to use async and await to access the external Url.
eg

Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()

```
'Dim urlContents As Byte() = Await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url).
```